# python сравнивать каждый элемент массива с переменной, вернуть успешный вариант

Tags: python, массивы

Есть массив содержащий цифры 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 
Есть переменная содержащая например 8

Как проверять все элементы массива на равенство (начиная с нуля), пока условие не вернет true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так.

Если надо прямо ручками пробежаться, то:

```
var = 8
result = false
numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for number in numbers:
  if number == var:
    result = true
    break
```

Если средставми python:

```
var = 8
numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
result = var in numbers
```